# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when scrolling too fast in ListView. Bug?

Tags: android, android-listview

So I have this custom `ListView` w/c has an embedded `OnSwipeLeft` and `OnSwipeRight` listeners and filled with an array of `TextViews`.

I'm currently on the stage of `App testing` then I have found this bug in my app. The error occurs when I'm doing the **scrolling-too-fast-up-and-down again-and-again**.

I put a `try-catch-block` on every array accessing in my code but the exception doesn't get caught up.

It seems to me that error occurs when I accidentally tap on one of `ListView`'s item while it is still scrolling (*The event occurs outside the clipping bounds of the `ListView`?*)

The exact error logs:

```
06-20 17:29:47.063: D/AndroidRuntime(18336): Shutting down VM
06-20 17:29:47.063: W/dalvikvm(18336): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.view.MotionEvent.getY(MotionEvent.java:903)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2184)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3446)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1691)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1125)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1675)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2194)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1878)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-20 17:29:47.092: E/AndroidRuntime(18336):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm quite sure that it's on the `SwipeListeners` because if I didn't set this

```
listView.setOnTouchListener( new OnSwipeTouchListener(this) {

    public void onSwipeRight() {

        loadNextPage();
    }
    public void onSwipeLeft() {

        loadPrevPage();
    }

});
```

No error occurring.

---

What I did to get rid of it is I look on the implementation of `SwipeListeners` w/c is exactly

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener
```

Then changing this default one

```
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

        return true;
    }
```

to this

```
    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

        return false;
    }
```

And the error has gone. But still this kind of work around will haunt me in my future work and I think nobody like it that way. What might be the things I missed?

Comment: are you using View Holder Pattern?

Comment: @SMR Uhm, I think no? I'm quite new in Android.

Comment: Array index outofbound happen only when your arraylist size is exceed or something wrong in arraylist you passed

Comment: @vadherjitendra It may be due to the internal/core implementation of the `SwipeListeners` itself wherein they used an array accessing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the **ViewHolder pattern** then you should use it as it makes `ListView` scrolling very smooth by reusing Views. few very good sources are:

1. [Holder Pattern](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterperformance_holder)
2. The [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)

Hope it helps. :)